# How to detect pole of meromorphic function using only a line?

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

As i already know, behaviour of meromorphic function is completly determined by its values on some line on  the domain.

Consider meromorphic function $f$
Suppose that we know everything about behaviour of $f$ on real axis.

> How to tell whether $f$ has pole or not.

Of course if $f$ blows up at point $a\in \mathbb{R}$ then it is a pole. I would like to consider how does pole which is out of line affect on behaviour of $f$

Comment: Searching for poles is equivalent to searching for zeros (under the map $z \mapsto 1/z$) and finding zeros is a serious problem even if we know values almost everywhere else; see the Riemann Hypothesis

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't in general : the analytic continuation **isn't continuous** with respect to the obvious parameters of the function.